# Shared memory for parallel processes

Tags: r, parallel-processing, shared-memory

It's been a while since the last time I looked (e.g. outdated [nws package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nws/index.html)) and so I wondered if anything "happened" in the meantime.

**Is there a way to share memory across parallel processes?**

I would like each process to have access to an `environment` object that plays the role of a meta object.

Answer (score 2):

The [rredis package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rredis/index.html) provides functionality that is similar to `nws`.  You could use `rredis` with the `foreach` and `doRedis` packages, or with any other parallel programming package, such as `parallel`.

Comment: Thanks Steve! Heard about it once or twice, but never really had a look into that package - until now ;-)

Comment: Though Redis values are limited to 512MB right? That could be a potential limitation... There is also Rdsm, which uses bigmemory as a backend to share memory, though that's only supported on Linux & Mac, not Windows...

Answer (score 1):

What will work quite efficiently is a shared matrix via the `bigmemory` package. You can serialize/unserialize pretty every R object into such matrix.

Unfortunately the only way you can share the matrices between the processes is via their descriptors, which are not deterministic (i.e. unless you communicate with the other process, you can not get a descriptor). To solve  this chicken-and-egg problem you can save the descriptor on the chosen location on the filesystem. (The descriptor is really small, the only non-trivial thing it contains is a memory address of the actual bigmatrx).

If you are still interested, I can post the R code.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds cool! Would love to see some code on this :-)

Comment: @Rappster I am making a proper R package for this. Give me a few days (I hope...)

Comment: Awesome!! I'll be looking forward to it

Comment: @Rappster FYI, the patch that fixed the nasty bug in the `bigmemory` package that prevented storing raw bytes was [just merged upstream](https://github.com/kaneplusplus/bigmemory/issues/42). So technically speaking my solution only started to be valid.

Comment: Social coding at its best! :-) Would you mind outlining your  approach using `bigmemory` with a short example?

Comment: @Rappster There are many small steps to be taken, that mostly concern synchronization. Look at the end of https://github.com/adamryczkowski/yaplr/blob/master/R/hello.R : `send_to_server` and `server_loop`. I'm sorry not everything is in English. Do you want to participate in the development?

Comment: Sure, let's connect via Github :-)

Comment: @Rappster OK, if you want, you can contact me there. I've translated everything into English, so the current logic should be easy to understand (although it is easy to mess up with all those mutexes...)

Comment: You should have gotten an email yesterday or so but your address at github seemed a bit "cryptic" so I might have gotten it wrong ;-) Alternatively, just send me your contact details to janko.thyson@rappster.de

Answer (score 1):

You can do this efficiently via a new [`yaplr`](https://github.com/adamryczkowski/yaplr) package.

First install it

```
devtools::install_github('adamryczkowski/yaplr')
```

R session number 1:

```
library(yaplr)
send_object(obj=1:10, tag='myobject')
# Server process spawned
```

R session number 2:

```
library(yaplr)
list_objects()
#          size                    ctime
# myobject   62 Sat Sep 24 13:01:57 2016
retrieve_object(tag='myobject')
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
remove_object('myobject')
quit_server()
```

The package uses `bigmemory::big.matrix` for efficient data transfer: when copying a big object between R processes no unnecessary copies are made: only one serialization and one unserialization.

No network sockets are used.

Comment: Very nice, I'll check it out!

Comment: Stumbling over the dependency on `synchronicity`: no windows binary available :-/

Comment: @Rappster True... I will post an issue to the author. Meanwhile maybe I should implement the mutexes myself - (the author wasn't very responsive to my previous issues). But it will take a few weeks.

Comment: @Rappster Install synchronicty by`devtools::install_github("kaneplusplus/synchronicity")` (https://github.com/kaneplusplus/synchronicity/issues/8#issuecomment-252523975)